# UIViewController SizeClass Compact and Regular in iOS8

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8

UiViewController sizeClass

in Potrait -

1) VerticalSizeClass - Regular
2) RegularSizeClass - Compact

in Landscape - 
1) VerticalSizeClass - Compact
2) RegularSizeClass - Compact

why?? What is Regular and Compact exactly means?